# MATLAB: Zeros appearing when storing values from different arrays to another array

Tags: arrays, matlab, zero

I have two double arrays like the ones below:

```
K>> var_conx

var_conx =
     1
     3
   127
   129
   216
   217
   252
   253
   302
   303
   342
   343
```

and

```
K>> var_cony

var_cony =
     2
   126
   128
   216
   217
   252
   253
   302
   303
   342
   343
```

My task is pretty simple, I only need to store in an another double array all the common values of the two arrays, let's call the other array "common_convar".
To be specific, for the two arrays above, i only want to store the values 216,217,252,253,302,303,342,343. For the other values, i do not care and i do not want them stored or whatever.

I have written the following code:

```
for i=1:length(var_conx)
    for j=1:length(var_cony)
        if var_conx(i)==var_cony(j)
           common_convar(i,:)=[var_conx(i)]; 
        end
    end
end
```

The problem i encountered here is that the array common_convar also stores some zeros in the beginning:

```
K>> common_convar

common_convar =

     0
     0
     0
     0
   216
   217
   252
   253
   302
   303
   342
   343
```

How is it possible to get rid of zeros and only store the desired common values of the two arrays var_conx and var_cony?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you could find the elements common to both arrays, without having to do nested loops,  using the  Matlab set intersect function:

```
common_values= intersect(var_conx,var_cony);
```

Then you could find the nonzero elements of the common array via logical indexing:

```
common_values = common_values(common_values > 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed worked just fine. But i have this question, why the way i tried to do it, these zeros were inserted into the array?

Comment: The loop method is mathematically OK but zero values will pass the test. You could still filter the zeros using the second step. Matlab should vectorize the intersect method and it should be faster than using the nested loops.

Comment: Alright, it worked perfectly. Strange though this thing with the zeros. Anyway, it is true that this method is much faster than a nested for loop, and it is just what i need. Thank you once again! :)

Comment: @NickH You get four initial zeros because the first value of `var_conx` that is present in `var_cony` is the _fifth_ (`216`). So the first assignment that is ever done is `common_convar(i,:)=...` when `i=5`. That statement automatically creates the array `common_convar` with zeros at the first four missing positions. The subsequent iterations will resize the array, and will also insert zeros if some `i` is "skipped", i.e. if there are no matches (that's not the case with your example data)